# Ubuntu 14.10 hibernate on notebook lid close

Tags: xubuntu, laptop, hibernate

i switch from xubuntu 13.10 to 14.10.

On 13.10 everthing works fine for me.
I try to hibernate notebook on close lid. Without look screen.

Things that happens.

```
1.) When i close lid, the notebook hibernates.
2.) When i open it without activated look screen, the notebook wakes up, but the screen is still black.
3.) When i open it with activated look screen,the notebook wakes up and ask for password on lock screen, after words the screen is going
to be black.
4.) When i choose "log out", "hibernate" on start menu, the notebook will hibernate. When i the close the lid and reopen it. The notebook
wakes up how it should.
```

Where is the different about the click on menu and the lid close action?

Answer (score 2):

Please see http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/10/enable-hibernate-option-in-ubuntu-14-10-unity/ for instructions on re-enabling hibernate.

Comment: Thanks hibernate will not work for my notebook. But it guides me to the right way how to activate the "right" suspend to on close lid.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue by disabling light locker and configured the supend by systemd.

http://sourcedigit.com/12976-shutdown-hibernate-ubuntu-14-10-automatically-laptop-lid-closed/